# Implementacion log_cambios Mysql... Como guardo el Usuario que actualizo, inserto o elimino el registro?

Tags: c#, mysql, trigger

Les comento que estoy realizando un log de cambios sobre una tabla en mysql, tengo el trigger que se ejecuta cada vez que actualizo, inserto o elimino y también tengo la tabla donde guardo los cambios, la sentencia con la que guardo el usuario que hizo el cambio es: current_user() pero esta sentencia solo me devuelve root@localhost . Mi pregunta es, existe una manera de guardar el usuario que invoco el trigger, de no ser asi, que me recomiendan para solucionar mi problemática... Muchas gracias de ante-mano

Comment: Si te refieres a usuario logeado en la aplicación (escritorio o web) debes tomar el nombre de este y incluirlo en el update/insert; current_user te pone "root..." por ser el usuario con que estan realizandose las operaciones a la BD, es el usuario con el cual estas accediendo a la BD.

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Si no sabes cómo hacer lo que describes en tu pregunta, investiga primero y actualiza tu pregunta con los enlaces de la investigación que hayas hecho. Hasta que no añadas mas información, me temo que tu pregunta quedará [en espera-¿Qué significa si una pregunta está "cerrada" o "en espera"?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: Tendre en cuenta como realizar una buena pregunta... Y por cierto ya di con la solución, solo necesitaba investigar un poco mas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya di con la solucion, investigando mas en profundidad la sentencia que debo utilizar no es current_user() sino que solo user() y con eso me guarda el usuario que realizo la accion sobre la tabla. Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Que bueno que hayas encontrado la respuesta. En cuanto puedas, [recuerda aceptar tu propia pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Saludos.